# Swift: Only one TableView Method is called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I run the app only `numberOfRowsInSection()` method is called. So i place the certain number of break point to the every method but I found that `numberOfRowsInSection()` is called 4-5 times rest of the method is not get called. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit


var arrSearch = [[String:Any]]()
class RecentSearchViewController: CustomNavigationViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tblSearch: UITableView!

    var searchBusVC:SearchBusViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

          if let arr = UserDefault["SearchTo"]{ 
          arrSearch.append(arr as! [String:Any])
        } 
        tblSearch.reloadData()
    }

extension RecentSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrSearch.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell") as! RecentCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let dict = arrSearch[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFrom.text = (dict["From"] as! String)
        cell.lblTo.text = (dict["To"] as! String)
        let strDate = Utill.getStringFromDate("EEE MMM dd ,yyyy", date: (dict["fromdate"] as! Date))
        cell.lblDate.text = strDate
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let searchvc = self.searchBusVC {
            searchvc.setRecentSearch(dict: arrSearch[indexPath.row])

        }
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}


class RecentCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lblFrom: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblTo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblDate: UILabel!

}
```

I tried many times but it's not going to work for me. Even in console there is no error is shown. Is there any issue with the code?

Comment: `cellForRowAt` data source method isn't called too?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called multiple times. But if this method returns `0`, then other methods are not called. Please check if the array `arrSearch` contains data.

Comment: no. @RobertDresler

Comment: Yes it's return 0. @Vishal

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia try adding some dummy data for testing then.

Comment: Sure let me try.  @Vishal

Comment: Why would it call the other methods if the number of rows is 0?

Comment: Why is `arrSearch` declared outside of the class? Why make it a global instead of a property of the class?

Comment: What is `UserDefault`? Always provide details about relevant variables in your code.

Comment: i try with the dummy count still it's call only one method.

Answer (score 0):

If `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, but no other `UITableViewDataSource` methods are, that must mean that `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0. And that must mean that `arrSearch` is empty. Also, this part of code

```
if let arr = UserDefault["SearchTo"] { 
      arrSearch.append(arr as! [String:Any])
}
```

Should be rewritten. Since you are casting the result of subscript, you can do that as a part of `if let`, which would also make it safer if the result isn't of `[String:Any]` type

```
if let arr = UserDefault["SearchTo"] as? [String:Any] { 
      arrSearch.append(arr)
}
```

In short, apparently `UserDefault["SearchTo"]` returns `nil`